# how to stop maven from downloading sources jar

Tags: maven

I am building a Spring boot application using maven. I included a jar file as dependency.
When the maven build is started, it is trying to download the jar by using the repository URL/groupId/ArtifactId/Version/ArtifactId-version-sources.jar

Both jar and repository are not public. In the repository I am not able to find any jar with "-sources" in its name and the download fails.

Dependency tag:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.app.internal</groupId>
        <artifactId>AppMaker</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.5</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Download link (which maven tries):

http://repo.aaa.com/com/test/app/internal/AppMaker/2.0.5/AppMaker-2.0.5-sources.jar

Actual jar link:

http://repo.aaa.com/com/test/app/internal/AppMaker/2.0.5/AppMaker-2.0.5.jar

How can I stop maven from downloading the sources jar?

Comment: The download of sources package will be done only if you configured your IDE or the maven build accordingly...

Comment: Can you please specify what type of configuration in maven does that?

Comment: Usualy only if you configure https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html  to do so or some special configurations with maven-assembly-plugin can do so... ?